# Google Maps and KML URL

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I need to build a simple map with checkboxes. Every checkbox must show different KML layer. I don't know how to build this, but in samples on Google Code I found below code.

But when I test all files on localhost (WAMP) KML layer is not showing when I click a checkbox. Other markers in JavaScript are showing normal, only KML is not.

Code to show KML layer is below. Please tell me how I can change code to grab markers.kml from specific URL and not in folder. I need to grab KML from other websites/servers.

```
/**
 * Toggles KML layer visibility.
 */
function toggleKmlLayer() {
  if (!kmlLayer) {
    var kmlUrl = window.location.href.substring(
        0, 1 + window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/')) + 'markers.kml';
    kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, {
      preserveViewport: false,
      suppressInfoWindows: false
    });
  }
  showKmlLayer = !showKmlLayer;
  if (showKmlLayer) {
    kmlLayer.setMap(map);
  } else {
    kmlLayer.setMap(null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your KML needs to be at a publicly available URL.  localhost is not publicly available (Google's servers can't access the KML).

[from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers)

> KML and GeoRSS Layers
>
> The Google Maps API supports the KML and GeoRSS data formats for displaying geographic 
>   information. These data formats are displayed on a map using a KmlLayer object, whose 
>   constructor takes the URL of a **publicly accessible** KML or GeoRSS file.

Comment: Thanks for this, but how can I change my code to grab KML file from live server (mydomain.com/markers.kml), but all javascript and html files is on localhost? Code in my question grab markers.kml from root folder, if I understand code? Again, I'm not a programmer, I just learn code with examples, but I must build this type of map for my project. Thanks for help!

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If the KML has a public URL, just use it.

Comment: Hey! Sorry for my bad English :( If I understand this line of code (0, 1 + window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/')) + 'markers.kml';) grab KML file from directory where is the JavaScript file. How can I change this line of code for grabing KML file from diferent URL and not the same directory where is the JS files? I hope you understand what I looking for.

Comment: What is the public URL of the KML?  Just use that (don't compute it from the location of the current page, which is what that code is doing).  See the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers)